# Spring Boot clean way to create self-pointing RestTemplate, that'd work both with normal running, and web integration test with random port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

To explain myself why I need this -- the application's main purpose is to wrap another web server, with intent to add restrictions and certain per-call calculations. This is achieved using zuul proxy and its filters. The application itself has to call that other web server intermediately as well, and often in context of certain user. Because of this, such intermediate calls are not done on the other web server directly, but looped over itself (ie RestTemplate is used, that points to application itself), so that if there are any security filters in place for the request, they would also be applied.

The definition for rest template looks like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate zuulRestTemplate(
    @Value("${server.port}") String port
) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .rootUri("http://localhost:" + port)
            .build();

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream()
            .filter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
            .map(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::cast)
            .findFirst().orElseThrow( () -> new RuntimeException("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found"));
    messageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new VavrModule());

    return restTemplate;
}
```

and this works for normal execution. The problem is with tests. Running whole test suite, a lot of tests failed with "port already in use" because it seems spring doesn't wait for one test to finish before launching the next. I found the solution is to specify WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT in the spring boot test annotation, however then my RestTemplate doesn't work anymore, because the server.port property is 0. I tried to solve this by adding `@Value("${local.server.port}")` parameter to my rest template bean function (as to use server.port if it's not 0, local.server.port if it is), however spring says it cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation, one rest client is calling another spring boot app and that one is calling itself and the port was defined is "8090" and I was running all from integration test with random port and

```
@LocalServerPort
int port;
```

got **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"** tried environment and couple of other methods but all failed, Solution for me is **ServletWebServerApplicationContext** example code is below

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    ServletWebServerApplicationContext ctx;

    @GetMapping("/port")
    public int printPort() {
        return ctx.getWebServer().getPort();
    }
}
```

I also suggest if you have multiple spring boot applications you can run all in one port with [this way](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/blob/5c74540d5ddd36f6492a3f8c9749dd12c41d8b90/spring-boot-1-5-cucumbertest-multi-module/module2/src/test/java/com/mascix/module2/CucumberSpringContextConfiguration.java#L22)